# Alternative to select/focus functions to automatically place cursor in textbox for Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I'm creating a survey in Qualtrics that needs to have an automatic cursor placed in textboxes so that participants can start typing without having to click the textbox. I was able to get this working using the following code :

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    $("QuestionID").select();

});
```

Unfortunately, this only works in the old Qualtrics survey builder (SE). This solution does not work in the new survey builder (JFE).

I've tried to find alternatives and none that work in SE seem to work in JFE. For example,

```
document.getElementById("QuestionID").select();
```

and

```
var input = document.getElementById('QuestionID');

input.select();
```

I've seen the focus function mentioned, but that doesn't work in either of the survey builders.

It seems that the new survey builder has issues with the select function, but after spending hours trying to find an alternative, I was not able to. I've tried obtaining a change log from Qualtrics, but they were not able to provide it.

I tried

```
$("QuestionID").focus();
```

and that did work in the old survey builder. Still does not work in new.

If I simply continue from the previous question in Qualtrics, the cursor doesn't work using focus(). However, if I refresh the page, focus does work. This is in the new survey builder. This still isn't a solution, but hopefully that provides some insight.

Does anyone know of any alternatives that could work?

Comment: So you have tried using `$("QuestionID").focus();` alread? Or what do you mean by "the focus function mentioned"? Did you try setting the focus by using `focus()` from the browser console?

Comment: That's correct. I've tried using $("QuestionID").focus(); separately, as well as the focus and select functions together . Neither worked in either of the survey builder versions. Could you expand on setting focus from the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the element id, not the function.  Try this, it will focus on the first text input field no matter what type of question it is:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $(this.questionId).down('.InputText').focus();
});
```

Comment: Is it just the way it is? or do I replace questionId with the actual question ID? The ID has a "~", which throws an error. I tried to use the code as is, and it behaves the same as with the other solution. It works in the preview (old survey builder), but doesn't work in the new survey builder, unless I refresh the page. Also, both focus() and select() provide the same behavior.

Comment: Just the way it is... this.questionId is a variable that contains the current question id. If you are in jfe preview mode with the mobile view on the right, it may look like the focus is only one view or the other, but if you type you'll see both views update.

Comment: One more thing...under Look & Feel set page transition to None.  This should always be done when using JavaScript in a survey.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work when using the actual survey link. It behaved exactly as you said in the preview where it would not show the cursor, but I could start typing. However, in the main survey nothing happened when I started typing.